# Let $A = \begin{pmatrix} a & b & c \\ 0 & a & b \\ 0 & 0 & a \\ \end{pmatrix} $. Find $A^n$

Tags: matrices

I am new here so please let me know if I must resentence the exercice. I considered it too short not to include it in the title too.

Let $ A=     \begin{pmatrix}     a & b & c \\     0 & a & b \\     0 & 0 & a \\     \end{pmatrix}$

Find $A^n$

I tried finding the matrix's first 4 or 5 powers and it looks like a pettern can be noticed but I can't seem to find a form for the element on line 3 row 3. I haven't tried using a binomial expansion though, writing the matrix as $$     \begin{pmatrix}     0 & b & c \\     0 & 0 & b \\     0 & 0 & 0 \\     \end{pmatrix}+ a    \begin{pmatrix}     1 & 0 & 0 \\     0 & 1 & 0 \\     0 & 0 & 1 \\     \end{pmatrix} $$

the second one being the identity matrix times $a.$

Comment: Why is it $A(x)$ and not just $A$? How does $x$ come into play?

Comment: Sorry, i was still thinking about my previous exercice

Comment: You should begin by noticing that $$\begin{bmatrix}     0 & b & c \\ 0 & 0 & b \\  0 & 0 & 0  \end{bmatrix}^{\large3} = \text{the $3\times3$ zero matrix}$$ and $$ \left( a  \begin{bmatrix}  1 & 0 & 0 \\  0 & 1 & 0 \\  0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \right)^{\large n} = a^n \begin{bmatrix}  1 & 0 & 0 \\  0 & 1 & 0 \\  0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**

If $$N=\begin{pmatrix}0&b&c\\0&0&b\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix},$$
then $$A=aI+N$$

(where $I$ is the identity matrix), and $N^3=0$. Applying [Binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) yields $$A^n=(aI+N)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k} a^{n-k}N^k=\cdots$$

Comment: I mentioned taking this method into consideration at the very end but thanks for letting me know it's the right one

Comment: @Dareal162: Well, you can still compute $A^n$ brute force if you wish, but this will be very long... and if you wish an other method, as far as I know, there are none...

Comment: Sorry if i'm being annoying but $N^4=0$, not $N^3$

Comment: You are obviously not annoying (and I can make mistake, so it's a good thing to mention them). So, I agree that $N^k=0$ for all $k\geq 3$, and thus, as you mentionned, $N^4=0$. But $N^3=0$ as well. In general, if $N\in \mathcal M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$ is nilpotent, then $N^n$ must holds.@Dareal162

Comment: Oh yeah, now i see... damn you calculus...

Comment: @Surb : You seem to be quite active here so it should be worth the trouble to notice this typographical difference:
$$
\begin{align}
& \sum_{k=0}^n \binom n o a^{n-k} N^k = ... \\ {} \\
\text{versus } & \sum_{k=0}^n \binom n o a^{n-k} N^k = \ldots \\ {} \\
\text{versus } & \sum_{k=0}^n \binom n o a^{n-k} N^k = \cdots
\end{align}
$$
The first one is akin to a spelling error; that's one of the reasons why `\ldots` and `\cdots` exist. Another is that in LaTeX (as opposed to MathJax, which is used here if you write `$a+b=...$` then you see [continued below] $\qquad$

Comment: $\qquad$something like $a+b=\text{...},$ i.e. you see neither $a+b=...$ nor $a+b=\ldots$ nor $a+b=\cdots. \qquad$

Comment: . . . and it's worth being aware of the following:
$$
\begin{align}
& a+b+\text{...}+z \\ {} \\
\text{versus } & a+b +...+z \\ {} \\
\text{versus } & a+b+\ldots+z \\ {} \\
\text{versus } & a+b+\cdots+z
\end{align}
$$
The first two above are incorrect usages by most standards. The first one is similar to what you get in full-fledged LaTeX if your code says `a+b+...+z`. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Thanks for the remark. On latex I always use \hdots, which doesn"t work here, and I didn't knew there were an other way to write it. So, thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=aI,Y=bJ$ and $Z=cJ^2$, where $J$ denotes the $3\times3$ nilpotent Jordan block. Then $X,Y,Z$ commute. Since $J^3=0$, among all degree-$n$ monomials of them, only $X^n,\,X^{n-1}Y,\,X^{n-1}Z$ and $X^{n-2}Y^2$ are nonzero. It follows that
\begin{aligned}
A^n
&=(X+Y+Z)^n\\
&=X^n+nX^{n-1}Y+nX^{n-1}Z+\binom{n}{2}X^{n-2}Y^2\\
&=\pmatrix{a^n&na^{n-1}b&na^{n-1}c+\binom{n}{2}a^{n-2}b^2\\ 0&a^n&na^{n-1}b\\ 0&0&a^n}.
\end{aligned}